# Display the border of the image onclick in toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here I want to display the border color of the image icons on click. I have 3 image which has default border set. i'm looking for displaying the icon border color on click like toggling each icons. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL8g3n97/)

```css
    .img-border {
      padding:5px;
      border:1px solid #db9c31;
      // background-color:#ff0;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="row header">
      <div class="col-3">
        <a class="align-middle no-padding" title="Home">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1391/1391667.svg" class="img-border" style="cursor:pointer" width="30px"
            height="30px">
        </a>
        <a class="align-middle no-padding" title="Home">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1391/1391667.svg" class="img-border" style="cursor:pointer" width="30px"
            height="30px">
        </a>
        <a class="align-middle no-padding" title="Home">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1391/1391667.svg" class="img-border" style="cursor:pointer" width="30px"
            height="30px">
        </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you try hard you would definitely find some answers on this topic already. But to give you an example of the approach, have a [look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9abt38eo/)

Things I have changed:

- Added a new `img` class storing the padding and the base border size
- Used the `img-border` class only to toggle the border color (if you remove the entire border, the image will jump 1px)
- Added a quick JS example of how you can approach the toggling (This is not a production code and browser compatible. This is only an example of the approach)

Here is the JS for reference:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const img = this.querySelector('img');
    img.classList.toggle('img-border');
  })
})
```